# How to cancel alarm manager alarms when user removes the app from recent apps list?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

As per a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658129/android-alarms-cancelled-when-application-is-killed) question : "Standard Android only allows you to remove things from that list on Android 3.0+, and doing so does not affect your AlarmManager events".

I would like to cancel the alarms if the user swipes the app from list of recent apps, but there seems to be no way we can handle the swiping of app from recent apps list where the alarm could be canceled.
I have option in the app for the user to cancel the alarm which executes this code :

```
public static void cancelAlarm() {
        if (alarmUp())
        {
            alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
  }
  public static boolean alarmUp() {
      return (pendingIntent != null);
  }
```

But how to cancel the alarm when the app removed forcibly ? I do not want to cancel the alarm when app is closed (by pressing back or home button).

Comment: Why removing the app from the recent list demands canceling the alarms you have set?

Comment: the alarms I am setting are periodic alarm, like when an alarm goes off, I create another, so wanted to cancel the alarm, as it may make the user think that removing that app has made periodic alarms stop.

Comment: I don't think your users will think of that, a better alternative would be a clear UI option in the app itself to cancel those alarms.

Comment: yes, there is an option for 'stop reminding'...will then proceed with storing the last alarm ring time in shared preferences then, for showing time left for next alarm ring, as closing the app resets the last alarm ring time.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps needed to accomplish this:

1. **Detect the app removal from the recents list.** See [What Exactly Happens When You Swipe An Android App From the Recent Apps List?](http://www.howtogeek.com/169549/what-exactly-happens-when-you-swipe-an-android-app-from-the-recent-apps-list/). That's the best info I found on the subject.
2. **Cancel the alarm.** Your question assumes that the `pendingIntent` variable still holds an intent constructed earlier. This won't work in an activity that was unloaded. Instead, construct an intent that's ["equal to"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) the original intent ("their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same"), and cancel that one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by calling `alarm.cancel()` in `OnDestroy()` of `Activity`.